# How to analyse emission spectra/absorbance spectra to show quenching

Tags: photochemistry

I have two samples with different chemical structures (but with the same core which is a fluorophore) and I need to prove that a structural change has resulted in the quenching of the fluorophore. Stern-volmer analysis would not be suitable as the molecular part which is believed to cause quenching is intramolecularly incorporated inside the molecule (not intermolecular). Sample A (without the quencher)'s max. emission intensity is much higher (sample A is almost two-fold higher), as compared to the Sample B (with the quencher).
[image]
(in case it's helpful, x and y has a difference of 1.04 nm.)
With the information above, can I conclude that the quenching is happening? Can I say, with the info above, that the absorbance baviours are similar but the emission behaviours are different?